# Too Many Arguments for Format - C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on learning C but these data types are tripping me up. I don't understand why these pointers don't resolve to the chars I'm referencing in board. I have a warning that says "Too many arguments for format".

```
char board[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

int main(){

    void printBoard(){
        printf("  c%  | c% |  c% \n", board[0], board[1], board[2]);
        printf(" -----------\n");
        printf("  c%  | c% |  c% \n",  board[3],  board[4],  board[5]);
        printf(" -----------\n");
        printf("  c%  | c% |  c% \n",  board[6],  board[7],  board[8]);
        printf(" \n");
        printf(" \n");

        }
}
```

Comment: `c%` --> `%c`...

Comment: My C/C++ is very rusty, but I'm pretty confident the % comes first, then the c.

Comment: And C doesn't support nested functions

Comment: "I'm working on learning C...". And where did you learn that you can define one function inside another function???

Comment: That's not how I actually have it, just threw it together to get some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your printf format specifiers should be %c and not c%.

now the compiler is interpreting your format as 
"%  |  c" hence "too many arguments for format".